# Ruby Proc syntax usage

Tags: ruby, proc

```
my_proc = proc{|x| "this is #{x}"}
```

given `my_proc`, what makes the following syntax work?

```
my_proc.call("x") # makes sense

my_proc.("x") # not really sure but ok

my_proc["x"] # uhhh....

my_proc === "x" # what the deuce?!
```

Comment: Most of your questions can be answered if you read [the manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Proc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are specifically asking about the syntax, this has nothing to do with `Proc`s. Ruby doesn't allow objects to change the syntax of the language, therefore it doesn't matter what kind of objects we are talking about.

```
my_proc.call("x")
```

This is just standard message sending syntax. It sends the message `call` with the argument `"x"` to the object returned by evaluating the expression `my_proc`.

You are asking "what makes this syntax work". Well, this is just how message sending is specified in the Ruby Language Specification.

```
my_proc.("x")
```

This is syntactic sugar for `my_proc.call("x")`, i.e. exactly what we had above: sending the message `call` with argument `"x"` to the result of evaluating `my_proc`.

If you want to make this work for your objects, you need to respond to `call`.

This syntax was added in Ruby 1.9 to make calling a "function-like object" look more like sending a message, with the only difference being the additional period character. Note that Ruby is not the only language using this syntax, [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) uses it as well.

```
my_proc["x"]
```

This is syntactic sugar for `my_proc.[]("x")`, i.e. sending the message `[]` with argument `"x"` to the result of evaluating `my_proc`.

If you want to make this work for your objects, you need to respond to `[]`.

`Proc#[]` was added as an `alias_method` of `Proc#call`, so that calling a "function-like object" looks more like sending a message, with the only difference being the shape of the brackets. With the addition of the `.()` syntax sugar in Ruby 1.9, I generally prefer that one.

```
my_proc === "x"
```

This is syntactic sugar for `my_proc.===("x")`, i.e. sending the message `===` with argument `"x"` to the result of evaluating `my_proc`.

If you want to make this work for your objects, you need to respond to `===`.

This was added so that `Proc`s could be used as conditions in `case` expressions and in `Enumerable#grep`, both of which use `===` to determine whether or not an object could be subsumed unter a category.

Answer (score 2):

About `===`:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D

> proc === obj → result_of_proc
>
> Invokes the block with obj as the proc's parameter like #call. It is
>   to allow a proc object to be a target of when clause in a case
>   statement.

That means you can use it in `case` statements, like this:

```
odd = proc { |x| x % 2 != 0 }
even = proc { |x| x % 2 == 0 }
case 1
when odd then 'odd'
when even then 'even'
end
# => "odd"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby often has several syntaxes for the same method, to best fit the develloper needs.

- `my_proc === "x"` : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D
  -> this one is said to be useful in `case` statements (@Marek_Lipka explained it further in his answer)
- `my_proc["x"]` : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D -> This one is said to be "syntax sugar", hiding the method's name for a more compact syntax.